# Bit shifting masks still elude me

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Could someone please take a look at this sloppy code and explain to me why it does not work. Am I packing and unpacking things correctly? (the object of this lab was to pack a date using bit shifting and masking. For example console input of 31/12/99 would be OR'ed together then AND'ed out, which is what my code was attempting to do. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define DAY_MASK 0x3e0
#define MONTH_MASK 0xc00
#define YEAR_MASK (~0x3180)

void hr()
{
    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
}

void fields()
{
    printf("     Binary\t\tDTG\t\tBase 10\n");
}

void prnFields(unsigned int *day, unsigned int *month, unsigned int *year)
{
    printBits(day);
    printf("\tDay\t\t%u\n", day);
    printBits(month);
    printf("\tMonth\t\t%u\n", month);
    printBits(year);
    printf("\tYear\t\t%u\n", year);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int packed;

    printf("Enter numeric Day\t:");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    printf("Enter numeric Month\t:");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("Enter two digit Year\t:");
    scanf("%d", &year);
    printf("\n");

    hr();
    printf("\nPrepacked Date\n");
    fields();
    hr();
    prnFields(day, month, year);
    hr();

    packed = day; packed <<= 9;
    packed |= month; packed <<= 4;
    packed |= year;
    printf("\nPacked Date\n");
    fields();
    hr();
    printBits(packed);printf("\t\t\t%d\n", packed);
    hr();
    printf("\nUnpacked Date\n");
    fields();
    hr();
    printBits((packed & DAY_MASK));
    printf("\tDay\t\t%d \n", (packed & DAY_MASK) >> 9);
    printBits((packed & MONTH_MASK));
    printf("\tMonth\t\t%d \n", (packed & MONTH_MASK) >> 5);
    printBits((packed & YEAR_MASK));
    printf("\tYear\t\t%d \n", (packed & YEAR_MASK));
     //system("pause");
    return(0);
}

void printBits(unsigned short int value)
{
    unsigned short int mask =1;
    int i;
    mask<<=15;

    for(i=1; i<=16; i++)
    {
        putchar( (mask&value)? '1': '0');

        if(i%8==0)
        {
            putchar(' ');
        }

        value<<=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: when it runs, If I enter a date of 31,12,99 I should get the same results on the output side but I don't. Most likely due to bad shifting and/or masking, which is where I think I need the most help.

Comment: How do you get the year to fit into four bits?

Comment: packed = day; packed <<= 9;
    packed |= month; packed <<= 4;
    packed |= year;

Comment: Month is only 1-12 -- that would fit into four bits but you give it 9.  Year would take 7 bits, but you give it only 4.

Comment: YEAR_MASK seems strange to me. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: You're effectively ORing month and year together, because you shift month up 4 when you need 7 to make room for year.

Comment: I'm not sure on the mask, i've been Googel'ing to find a good text on how to derive my mask. My current masks are bad guesses at best.

Comment: Write out in binary the max numbers you need to represent.  Max day is 31 -- 11111.  Max month is 12 -- 1100.  Max year is 99 -- 1100011.  So you need 5 bits for day, 4 for month, 7 for year.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm grasping this now. "packed <<= 4" does nothing more than shift 4 bits within packed and then "packed |= month" would place the 4 bit month in the space we just alloted. Is that correct? How do I figure out my mask?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't be shifting Packed, rather I'd be shifting your days, years, months, etc.  IE `Packed |= (day >> somenumber)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have too few bits assigned for Month (0xc00) and the way you do it it's not easy to see whether your shifts are correct.

I'd suggest to define your constants in a more consistent way like this:

```
#define DAY_BITS   5
#define MONTH_BITS 4
#define YEAR_BITS  7

#define DAY_OFFSET   YEAR_BITS
#define MONTH_OFFSET ( YEAR_BITS + DAY_BITS )
#define YEAR_OFFSET  0

#define DAY_MASK   ~( ~0 << DAY_BITS   )
#define MONTH_MASK ~( ~0 << MONTH_BITS )
#define YEAR_MASK  ~( ~0 << YEAR_BITS  )
```

... now you can set the packed value like this:

```
packed = 0;
packed |= ( day   & DAY_MASK   ) << DAY_OFFSET;
packed |= ( month & MONTH_MASK ) << MONTH_OFFSET;
packed |= ( year  & YEAR_MASK  ) << YEAR_OFFSET;
```

... and get the single fields like this:

```
printf("\tDay\t\t%d \n",   ( packed >> DAY_OFFSET   ) & DAY_MASK );
printf("\tMonth\t\t%d \n", ( packed >> MONTH_OFFSET ) & MONTH_MASK );
printf("\tYear\t\t%d \n",  ( packed >> YEAR_OFFSET  ) & YEAR_MASK );
```

You could now simply change the order of the fields in your offset definitions to make the dates easily sortable:

```
#define DAY_OFFSET   0
#define MONTH_OFFSET DAY_BITS
#define YEAR_OFFSET  ( DAY_BITS + MONTH_BITS )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to follow how you did it and grasp the concept.

Answer (score 3):

The code to pack a date is wrong. Draw a diagram for each step that shows what each bit will contain, like this (where 'D' is a bit that is used for the day, 'M' is a bit that is used for the month, 'Y' is a bit that is used for the year, and '?' are bits that are corrupted because they contain both month and year):

```
packed = day;     // 0000000000000000000DDDDD
packed <<= 9;     // 0000000000DDDDD000000000
packed |= month;  // 0000000000DDDDD00000MMMM
packed << 4;      // 000000DDDDD00000MMMM0000
packed |= year;   // 000000DDDDD00YYY????YYYY
```

Note: Your masks look like this in binary:

```
DAY_MASK   = 000000DDDDD00000
MONTH_MASK = 0000MM0000000000
YEAR_MASK  = YY00YYY00YYYYYYY
```

Without doing your homework for you; I'd strongly recommend that you do the same thing I did: write everything out in binary so you can see which bits are doing what.

Answer (score 0):

So where do we start?
Day is max 31, so you need log(32) = 5 bits for that but you don't care about this yet.
Months is max 12 so you need log(16) = 4 bits for that
Year is max 99 so you need log(128) = 7 bits for that

Put day in your variable.
Now shift to the left to make room for the month (4 bits)
put the month in
now shift to the left to make room for the year (7 bits)

Now to unpack first get days.  Undo both shifts.
Then to get months undo just the years shift.
To get years you don't need to shift, just the mask.

Since the masks are the last n bits of the number where n is the number of bits you are interested in, the masks are 2^n - 1 where n is the number of bits for days, months, years.